# Software manager failed to install package. Internet connection fine. sudo apt-get install fluidsynth doesn't work

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates

I'm trying to download `Fluidsynth`. When I attempt to download it via Software Manager, it gives me this message:

```
Failed to download package files. Check your internet connection.
```

As you can probably tell, my internet connection is just fine. No issues or anything. I then searched for another way, and found the `sudo apt-get install` solution. It didn't help, and gave me this message at the end of a wall of text:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I then attempted `sudo apt-get update`, and upon running, a massive wall of text appeared, I noticed some errors throughout it as it scrolled up quickly, and in the end it gave me this message:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

All variants of "fix-missing" that I tried weren't recognized, though I doubt that it would be much help either way.

I really want to get `Fluidsynth` and I've had this problem before with things like `Kdenlive` and `Openshot` as well. I found the `Fluidsynth` website and downloaded the latest version, and it came in a `.tar.bz2` file that I extracted, and found a bunch of files that I have no Idea what to do with. I did, however, open and read the READMEs, but they gave me no insight as to how to open or run the synthesizer. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
```

again and got this message:

```
fluidsynth is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 280 not upgraded.
```

I could really use some assistance, please.

Comment: Please re-run `sudo apt-get update` and include the complete output in your question (see [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/152371/175814)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with errors during sudo apt-get update, that could be a server being down temporarily or permanently. You could try changing the main software source download server to another source.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server

Under "Download from", change from main server to other, and either click the "select best server" button or choose the one that looks nearest to your location.

Once you get a clean update try installing again.

However if you already received "fluidsynth is already the newest version" Then that should mean it's installed. Perhaps one of the attempts you made actually worked and you hadn't noticed.

Try running it either from terminal or from the dash menu.

Comment: You have my sincerest gratitude for helping me sort out most of the problem. There is a different, seemingly easier to solve error keeping the program from running, but everything else is cleared up thanks to your input. It may have been naive of me to have initially believed I would somehow find a way to get a working desktop shortcut for the application.